# Does anyone know of resources for the Oracle 1Z0-072 exam objectives?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am currently studying for the Oracle 1Z0-072 certification exam and I'm finding some of the early objects very ambiguous and difficult to study for.  Topics such as:

- Relational Database Models
- Connecting to Oracle Databases

What do they mean by those? What skills or knowledge do I need to possess?

Thanks in advance for any direction or insight!

https://education.oracle.com/oracle-database-12c-r2-administration/pexam_1Z0-072

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Relational Database Models

It is a basic DBA exam. I think they meant [Relational Data Structures](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/oracle-relational-structures.html), which you would need anyway. Maybe this specific part: [Introduction to Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/introduction-to-oracle-database.html#GUID-A42A6EF0-20F8-4F4B-AFF7-09C100AE581E). Nothing complicated, I have never ever encountered a modeling question on the exams from the DBA track.

- Connecting to Oracle Databases

My bet is on [Configuration and Administration of Oracle Net Services](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/netag/part-II-config-and-admin-of-oracle-net-services.html). Connection Manager is the odd one here, it is nice to know what it is, but I don't think the details are needed, it is a very rarely used feature.

Both of the above chapters cover other exam topics as well.

Comment: the page you linked also had a link for the _authorized_ practice exam.  I highly recommend it.  But use it as a study guide.  Don't try to memorize answers, because _those_ questions won't be on the exam.  The _subject_ of the questions will be on the exam.  Don't look for exam dumps.  If Oracle discovers you've used them they reserve the right to pull your cert and ban you from future certs.

Answer (score 0):

Just a willlddd guess here.

> Relational Database Models

- Normalization.
- EAV Tables
- Denormalization.

> Connecting to Oracle Databases

- configuring a user
- [connecting with SQL*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b12170/qstart.htm%60isql)